# Проблема с очисткой памяти после удаление строки в Си

Tags: c

Проблема с очисткой памяти в Си. Моя задача заключается в удаление k строки в матрице. Программа работает корректно, если убрать очистку память, однако если ее вернуть в код о return 0 можно забыть. С чем это связано?
Исправленный код ниже:

```
    int remover(int **a, int size, int sizev, int k)
{
    for(int i = k;i<size-1;i++)
    {
        a[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    size--;
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < sizev; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return size;
}
```

main:

```
    int main() {
    int **a;
    int size = 3, sizev = 3;
    a = (int **) malloc(size * sizeof(int *));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        a[i] = (int *) malloc(sizev * sizeof(int));
        for (int j = 0; j < sizev; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 9;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizev; j++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\nk\n");
    int k;
    scanf_s("%d", &k);
    size = remover(a, size, sizev, k);
    for(int i = 0;i<size;i++)
    {
        free(a[i]);
    }
    free(a);
}
```

Comment: Ошибочки проверять не забывайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы вот тут

```
a = (int**)realloc(a,(size-1)* sizeof(int*));
```

меняете адрес, хранящийся в `a`, только вот тут

```
remover(a,size,size_t,k);
```

у вас передача *копии* `a`, так что вы пытаетесь освобождать совсем другую память... Вы **не сохраняете** новый указатель.

И - я бы не использовал `size_t` как имя переменной - потому как это по сути предопределенный тип - см. https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t

Как оно вообще у вас скомпилировалось?...